# How do hosts from different organisations participate as orderers in Hyperledger Fabric V1?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Just looking at crypto-config.yaml for example - if I have an domain and host declared in OrdererOrgs, does this mean I will generate the certificates and keys for that particular host to sign proposed blocks?

If this host is on a separate VPN, what is the best practice for this host to take part in consensus (for example ipsec tunnel)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to have very clear how is going to be your network, i.e. how many peers and orderers are going to compose your network. There, you can define an orderer or more for each organization.

Then, you start generating the elements that you need for your network:

- The cryptogen tool generates you the certificates that you need for your network. You should define the crypto-config.yaml according with your network. If you have a domain and host declared in OrdererOrgs, it will generate the certificates and keys for that particular Orderer.
- The configtxgen tool generates you the configuration for your channel. There, int the configtx.yaml, you define wich elements are gointo to take part in your channel.